# How can I use the new `@for` loop syntax for dynamic forms?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm following the [Angular 17 guide on dynamic forms](https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms#example-30). In this code snippet, they show how to loop using `ngFor` to dynamically display an array of form controls.

```
<div formArrayName="aliases">
  <h2>Aliases</h2>
  <button type="button" (click)="addAlias()">+ Add another alias</button>
  <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; let i=index">
    <!-- The repeated alias template -->
    <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Alias:</label>
    <input id="alias-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use the [new `@for` loop syntax](https://angular.dev/essentials/conditionals-and-loops#for-block) introduced in Angular 17 here instead? I tried the following:

```
<div formArrayName="aliases">
  <h2>Aliases</h2>
  <button type="button" (click)="addAlias()">+ Add another alias</button>
  @for (alias of aliases.controls; track $index; let i = $index;) {
    <div>
      <!-- The repeated alias template -->
      <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Alias:</label>
      <input id="alias-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

But I get the error that `Property $index does not exist on ...`

I was expecting the for loop syntax I used to produce the same results as the example shown which uses ngFor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52528) with the aliasing where `let i = $index;` earases the `$index` so it doesn't work on track:

You can fix it this way:

```
 @for (alias of aliases.controls; let i =$index; track i; ) {
    <div>
      <!-- The repeated alias template -->
      <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Alias:</label>
      <input id="alias-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  }
```

Or even better, you don't even need the alias anymore, you can directly use the implicit `$index` in the template

```
 @for (alias of aliases.controls; track $index) {
    <div>
      <!-- The repeated alias template -->
      <label for="alias-{{ $index }}">Alias:</label>
      <input id="alias-{{ $index }}" type="text" [formControlName]="$index">
    </div>
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears there is some confusion in your attempt to use the new @for loop syntax in Angular 17. The correct syntax for looping through form controls in a form array in Angular 17 is as follows:

```
<div formArrayName="aliases">
  <h2>Aliases</h2>
  <button type="button" (click)="addAlias()">+ Add another alias</button>

  <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; index as i">
    <!-- The repeated alias template -->
    <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Alias:</label>
    <input id="alias-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControl]="alias">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the updated syntax, you use *ngFor to iterate through the form controls in aliases.controls. The let alias syntax allows you to reference the current form control in the loop, and index as i allows you to get the index. Then, you can use [formControl]="alias" to bind the form control to the input.

The @for syntax you attempted is not valid for this use case. The correct Angular 17 syntax uses the *ngFor directive with the specified variable names for the current item and index. The trackBy function is not needed in this case.

Comment: @for is just fine for this usecase, see my answer.